# How to get element width or height in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I can't get the real width or height after image loaded. Does anyone know how to do it in the correct way?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="editor-container">
    <img src="{{photoUrl}}" alt="" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.editor-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.editor-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

**TypeScript:**

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
    try {
        console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('editor-container') );
        console.log( document.getElementsByClassName('editor-container')[0] );
        console.log( 'clientWidth', document.getElementsByClassName('editor-container')[0].clientWidth );
        console.log( 'scrollWidth', document.getElementsByClassName('editor-container')[0].scrollWidth );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

**result**:

[the console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp4I3.png)

Comment: Do you mean the actual width as in what size the image is set to? Because the current way it's set right now there's a div that limits the size of your image.

Comment: @MikeTung Thanks for response! I remove 'width: 100%;' in the .editor-container style, then it works now.

Comment: mind picking my solution once I post?

Comment: I was trying to set the image width. I ended up using your suggested `.scrollWidth` into a variable, and then `<img src="" width="{{maxWidth}}" />` Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved because the div was limiting the size of the picture.

### CSS

```
.editor-container {
  position: relative;
}

.editor-container img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}
```